# Is it ineffecient to use a jQuery extension to create your HTML?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been using [domec](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-domec/). Are plug-ins like these much more inefficient than just using jQuery's built in methods?

Comment: If you want to test performance, check out [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/).  Create some test cases, and viola!

Comment: @gnarf: +1 Awesome tool. Thanks gnarf, I have never heard about this. This may very well answer be the answer to most of my programming questions lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on HOW you are adding the html.  If you are using methods such as .html() or innerHTML that do not manipulate the DOM, these are inherently faster than DOM manipulating functions such as .append().  Each has a different purpose.

To answer your question: yes, it is potentially inefficient to do this.  An extension is only going to give you jQuery's native performance AT BEST.  The fastest you could achieve would be to write fully optimized javascript.

Your question is analogous to, "Is inefficient to use a PHP framework to generate your webpages compared to compiled C code?"

Answer (score 0):

The goal of products like domec are to make coding easier, not the code more efficient.  Look at the source code ... a lot is being done to simply replace a line or two of jquery.

Comment: Worth is subjective, but perhaps you were hoping for a more quantified *cost*?

Comment: @Kirk: Yes, like benchmarks. Im really wondering if the trade off is worth it.

Comment: If you app is extremely performance critical, then it's not worth it.  If this is a typical web-site/web-application without a lot of animation or constant visual effects, go for it if you really feel like it would make your development more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Any time you compromise convenience for efficiency (one way or the other), you're making a choice.  If it's worth it or not depends on the application.  Sometimes, the environment your application will be executed in has plenty of leeway, and efficiency is just not a concern.  Other times, speed is of the essence, and it's worth the developer's time to spend a few extra hours to save the end user a few seconds.

Bottom line, you have to make your own decisions.  If performance is an issue, benchmark your code, and use the data you collect decide.